# Error trying to make a basic ThreadManager in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading

I haven't coded much for probably a few years, and I wanted to make a really basic thread manager in C++ for an idea I had. I have ran into an issue where I get this error:

> ThreadManager.cpp:49:37: error: cannot convert
>   'ThreadManager::updateLoop' from type 'DWORD (ThreadManager::)(LPVOID)
>   {aka long unsigned int (ThreadManager::)(void*)}' to type
>   'LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE {aka long unsigned int
>   (**attribute**((**stdcall**)) *)(void*)}'

Yet, I don't know how to attempt to fix it. Here is my code, I couldn't figure out how to paste it in here with formatting. It said I needed 4 spaces on each line but that seemed like would take a while, so I put it on pastebin:

ThreadManager.cpp: http://pastebin.com/2bL3mTqv

ThreadManager.h: http://pastebin.com/7xETj5BK

Like I said, I haven't programmed much for a LONG time, and I am trying to get back into it with what I remember, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Also, if you have any suggestions for modifications to my code to make it better, please let me know! I know it is not good OOP at all, and there is no reusability pretty much, but this is the first draft, and first program I have written for a while.

Comment: First off, don't use `TerminateThread`.  Secondly, if you have C++11 available, just use `std::thread`, or barring that use `boost::thread`.  They provide a nice interface that makes certain things much easier than dealing directly with the `Win32` API.

Comment: Thread function cannot be a member function. At least not this way. You have to use either a normal function (not a method) or a static method of a class.

Comment: Yup - like @DiegoSevilla posts, call a static method and pass 'this' as the void* parameter.  Cast it back in the static and you can then call an instance method on it.

Comment: Also, threadpools are more easily and simply implemented by having the threads loop around a blocking producer-consumer queue pop, getting task objects and calling a 'run' method - abstract so it must be implemented in task descendants.

Answer (score 0):

The comments have said the basics, but here's it spelled out: you can't pass in a method to a class when a call is expecting a normal function.  To do what you want, I'd do the following:

```
// New Function
void threadMain(void* classPointer)
{
    ThreadManager* realClass = (ThreadManager*)classPointer;
    realClass->updateLoop();
}

ThreadManager::ThreadManager(int max)
{
    // Assign maxThreads to max value
    maxThreads = max;

    // Start updateThread, and let it run updateLoop() until terminated
    updateThread = CreateThread(
                                NULL,       // default security attributes
                                0,          // use default stack size
                                threadMain, // thread function name
                                this,          // argument to thread function
                                0,          // use default creation flag
                                NULL);      // ignore thread identifier

    // Check the return value for success
    // If failed, exit process.
    if (updateThread == NULL) {
        ExitProcess(3);
    }      
}
```

Now I know you want an extra argument, so probably use std::tuple to pass in the "this" pointer and any extra arguments you actually want.

Now having said all of that, take the advice of others and use [std::thread](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread) and such, not the win32-specific calls unless you really need to.